# Outlook Appointment isn't showing Attendees that have been added

Tags: vba, outlook, appointment

I'm having some problems with some pieces of code that I've Frankenstein'd from the web. I have a Word document that uses a command button to run a piece of code, the end result being an Outlook Appointment being generated with a template added, as well as recipients. I've used 2 different methods, and they each present their own problem.

Method 1: Generates the Appointment, includes and displays the attendees, but **does not allow for HTML formatting of the body**

---

```
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim OMail As Object
Dim xMeeting As Object
Dim xDoc As Object
Dim myRequiredAttendee As Outlook.Recipient
Dim myOptionalAttendee As Outlook.Recipient
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xEmail = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set xDoc = ActiveDocument
opCancel = False

Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xMeeting = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
Set myRequiredAttendee = xMeeting.Recipients.Add(EMAIL ADDRESSES)
myRequiredAttendee.Type = olRequired
Set xDoc = ActiveDocument

With xMeeting
    .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
    .Display
    .Subject = "MEETING SUBJECT"
    .Duration = 60
    .Body = "MESSAGE BODY THAT I'D LIKE TO FORMAT, BUT THIS METHOD DOESN'T PERMIT HTML"

End With

Set xDoc = Nothing
Set xMeeting = Nothing
Set xOutlookObj = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Method 2: Generates the Appointment, allows for HTML formatting of the body, loads the attendees but **does not display them**. When I click the 'Invite Attendee' button in the invite, they all appear (so they're obviously being loaded).

```
Dim olapp As Outlook.Application, appt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim m As Outlook.MailItem
Dim rtf() As Byte

Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
Set m = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set appt = olapp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

appt.Display
appt.Subject = "MEETING SUBJECT"
appt.Duration = 60
appt.RequiredAttendees = "EMAIL ADDRESSES"

m.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
m.HTMLBody = "<font style=""color: red;"">VERIFY SUBJECT LINE & MEETING START TIME ARE CORRECT, THEN DELETE THIS LINE" & _
        "<font style=""color: black;""><p>REST OF TEXT BODY</P>
m.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Copy
appt.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Paste
m.Close False 'don't save...
```

What I'm looking for is code that creates the Appointment, **loads and displays** the attendees, **and allows HTML formatting** of the body. Also, I can't use the .send command because the body of the invite still needs to be edited before it's sent - which is why I'd like the attendees to be displayed to avoid confusion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#1 is fine, but `AppointmentItem` object does not directly support HTML - you get either plain text `Body` property or RTF formatted (array of byte) `RtfBody` property. You needed to either generate the appropriate RTF, or use `AppointmentItem.GetInspector().WordEditor` (returns Word's `Document` object) to produce the suitably formatted body.

Comment: Just to be clear - only 1 or the other would run (not both). To answer your comment to #2 first - I'm not sure how it does it, but the end result is nearly the same as #1 - an Appointment is generated with the formatted text (top line in red, rest in black), and the Attendees are loaded - they're just not SHOWN.

As far as #1 - can you give me a little help with 'generating the appropriate RTF', or word editor bit? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use `appt.Recipients.AddRecipient` to add one attendee at a time?

Comment: I just adjusted #2 to that, and I get a run-time error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Sorry, it is supposed to be `appt.Recipients.Add("user@domain.demo")`

Answer (score 0):

The following code generates the appointment, loads the recipients and displays them, as well as formats the message body in HTML.

```vb
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim OMail As Object
Dim xMeeting As Object
Dim xDoc As Object
Dim myRequiredAttendee As Outlook.Recipient
Dim myOptionalAttendee As Outlook.Recipient
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xEmail = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set xDoc = ActiveDocument

Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xMeeting = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
Set myRequiredAttendee = xMeeting.Recipients.Add(EMAIL LIST)
myRequiredAttendee.Type = olRequired
Set xDoc = ActiveDocument

With xMeeting
    .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
    .Display
    .Subject = "MEETING SUBJECT"
    .Duration = 60
    
    '**
    xEmail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    xEmail.HTMLBody = "<font style=""color: red;"">VERIFY SUBJECT LINE & MEETING START TIME ARE CORRECT, THEN DELETE THIS LINE" & _
      "<font style=""color: black;""><p>THE REST OF APPT MESSAGE</p>"
    xEmail.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Copy
    xMeeting.GetInspector().WordEditor.Range.FormattedText.Paste
    '**

End With

Set xDoc = Nothing
Set xMeeting = Nothing
Set xOutlookObj = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

The ** part is what I changed to make this work.